# Різниця між словами "складнощі" та "складності"

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

Чи є різниця між словами "складнощі" та "складності"?

Тлумачення в СУМ й іншому словнику цих слів такі:

- > **[СКЛА́ДНІСТЬ](http://sum.in.ua/s/skladnistj)** 1, ності, жін. Абстр. ім. до [скл**а́**дний](http://sum.in.ua/s/skladnyj).
  >
  > **СКЛА́ДНІСТЬ** 2, ності, жін. Абстр. ім. до складн**и́**й. *Відзначаючи єдність живої і неживої природи, слід підкреслити складність хімічних сполук, властивих організмам* (Методика викладання анатомії.., 1955, 42); *Народе мій! При тракторнім рулі, У складності прекрасного комбайна Ти данину збираєш від землі, І в тебе казка — ніби річ звичайна* (Максим Рильський, III, 1961, 239); *Світ стає дедалі складнішим — але хай пильніше бачать наші очі всю цю складність* (Комуніст України, 8, 1966, 60); *Розмаїтість життєвих зв'язків, складність людських взаємин і разом в тим складність людської душі — ці те невичерпне джерело, що живить літературу* (Вітчизна, 8, 1970, 163); *Кібернетику цікавлять не всі керуючі системи, а тільки ті серед них, які досягли певного ступеня складності* (Робітнича газета, 21.X 1962, 2).
- > **[скла́днощі](http://sum.in.ua/f/skladnoshhi)**, -ів, мн.
  >
  > 1. Перешкоди, які складно вирішити, розв'язати, подолати.
  >    *Якусь мить поміркувавши, рабин повів нас уперед, перетинаючи хол навкоси, потім не без складнощів проминув заставлений старими меблями коридор..* (Брати Капранови, Розмір має значення, 2006).
  > 2. чого, які і без додатка. Те саме, що [труднощі](http://sum.in.ua/s/trudnoshhi) (у 2 знач.); скрута.
  >    *Деякі люди перебільшують складнощі мого тутешнього існування: повторюю, я живу, як студент* (Василь Стус, VI, 1997);
  >    *Машинка в білявки була, як на лихо, з механічною коробкою передач… Ясно, що з нею в білявки «У» були певні складнощі* (Ірена Карпа, Bitches Get Everything, 2007).

Із прикладів вживання обох слів можна побачити, що вони вживаються для передачі схожої семантики. То виходить, що ці слова тотожні?

Comment: Якщо те, що ви знайшли у словнику, свідчить про тотожність, то у чому са́ме полягає запитання?

Answer (score 3):

#### Однина/множина

Слова «скла́дність» і «тру́дність», на мою думку, порівняно рідко у сучасній мові вживаються у множині. [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), наприклад, узагалі не подають форм множини для цих слів.

«Скла́днощі» і «тру́днощі», навпаки, є суто множинними іменниками.

Хоча «складність»/«трудність» може позначати як абстрактне поняття, так і конкретні перешкоди при виконанні чогось (яких може бути багато), і відповідно уживання цих слів у множині теоретично має сенс, але в сучасній мові при необхідності вжити множину я би зазвичай надавав перевагу «складнощам»/«труднощам».

#### Як абстрактне поняття

Але: якщо за якихось причин є необхідність вжити у множині слово, що позначає саме абстрактне поняття (а не конкретні перешкоди), то, незважаючи на множину, я би вживав «складності»/«трудності».

Наприклад, якщо ми кожній задачі співвідносимо певну числову величину — її [складність](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) (або, припустимо, ми можемо вигадати ще одну числову величину — трудність, що, на відміну від складності, залежатиме не лише від задачі, а є різною для різних пар ⟨задача, виконавець⟩), то, відподвідно, маючи на увазі числовий показник під назвою «складність» («трудність»), ми скажемо «складності (трудності) цих двох задач істотно відрізняються» (а не «складнощі (труднощі) цих двох задач істотно відрізняються» — бо це буде вже інший зміст).